# Parsing json stored in localstorage - Error NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Tags: javascript, json, html, cordova, local-storage

I've read a lot of posts all around without success. I'm developing a simple set/get localstorage of a json stringified, as in the following [link](http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/).

Unfortunately, I always got this error:

> Request Failed: error, NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI
>   denied

This is a sniplet I'm using (just for my tests):

```
var id_expert = "1";
var testjson = "js/testjson.js"; 
$.getJSON(testjson)
          .done(function( data ) {

//////// STORE ///////////
                    window.localStorage.setItem("id_expert_selected", id_expert);
                    var list = 'questions_'+id_expert;
    window.localStorage.setItem(list,JSON.stringify(data));  

////////// RETRIEVE //////////////                  
                  var id_exp = window.localStorage.getItem('id_expert_selected');
    var list_answ = window.localStorage.getItem('questions_'+id_expert);
    var test = JSON.parse(list_answ) || {}; 

$.getJSON( test )
  .done(function( data ) { <---------- I'm not able to got it.
... bla bla bla...
```

In the sniplet, I store/retrive the json string, without the parsing success.
I'm sure the json is good because when I use it without the localstorage, I got the parsing.

Any clue?

EDIT:

I got the same result even using this:

```
$.getJSON( list_answ )
      .done(function( data ) { <---------- I'm not able to got it.
    ... bla bla bla...
```

I also tried changing a flag in Firefox config (some security stuff), but the error is still there.
On real Android device, in debug, I read another kind of error description:

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/cac…/previews/MyApp/1/%7B%22username%22:%22myusername%22,%22pwd%22:%22mypwd%22%7D
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Thanks to [MegaAppBear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4606862/megaappbear) I solved:

**//// STORE JSON /////**

```
window.localStorage.setItem("id_expert_selected", id_expert);
                    var list = 'questions_'+id_expert;
    window.localStorage.setItem(list,JSON.stringify(data));
```

**//// RETRIEVE JSON /////**

```
var id_expert = window.localStorage.getItem('id_expert_selected');
    var list_data = window.localStorage.getItem('questions_'+id_expert),
      def = $.Deferred();

    if (!list_data) {
        def = $.getJSON('js/test.json', function(data) {
            /// save data using localStorage.setItem
        });
    }else{
        list_data = JSON.parse(list_data);
        def.resolve();
    }

    def.done(function() {
var expert_name = document.getElementById('expert_name');
                expert_name.textContent = list_data.NameExpert;
..... and so on .......
```

Comment: Well, it seems that list_answ is a json string and your test variable is a json from the code you posted, so when you're trying to make the request like $.getJSON( test), the parameter you're passing is an object instead of the url as a string

Comment: I edited my question. I still got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you're trying to do here.

`var test = JSON.parse(list_answ) || {}; // This returns an object`

AND

`$.getJSON( test ); // this expects a uri`

Comment: Maybe a logic mistake, but I edited my question: I still got the same error

Comment: Still - "list_answ" is a json string, it's not a URI. Do you understand?

Comment: I think I'm starting understand now. Do you mean I can use getJSON using uri only, not an object or string stored. I also read this link that shed some light on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853016/jquery-getjson-how-to-avoid-requesting-the-json-file-on-every-refresh-caching

Comment: Yes. "getJSON" would retrieve some JSON data and on success give you back an object representation if that JSON string.